# How can I make a multiple Fetch Call in Ui5?

Tags: javascript, xml, api, sapui5

Hi I want to call these Fetch calls all together at the same time, so I have Tablets, Smartphones & Notebooks displayed. How do I do this? I tryed something with Async Function but it didnt worked out.

The Code:

```
onInit: function () {

                const tabletUrl = '/api/tablets?limit=1000&offset=0';

                fetch(tabletUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
                    const dataModel = new JSONModel();
                    dataModel.setData({
                        items: res
                    });
                    this.getView().setModel(dataModel, "aribadevices")

                })

                const notebookUrl = '/api/notebooks?limit=1000&offset=0';

                fetch(notebookUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
                    const dataModel = new JSONModel();
                    dataModel.setData({
                        items: res
                    });
                    this.getView().setModel(dataModel, "aribadevices")

                })

                const smartphonesUrl = '/api/smartphones?limit=1000&offset=0';

                fetch(smartphonesUrl).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
                    const dataModel = new JSONModel();
                    dataModel.setData({
                        items: res
                    });
                    this.getView().setModel(dataModel, "aribadevices")

                })

            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the requests running at the same time asynchronously.

I assume you want to set the data model once with the data from all three requests. In that case, I think using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to combine all your fetch promises would be a good solution.

Make sure to flatten the response from the combined promise in order to create a single array with [`<Array>.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const tabletUrl = '/api/tablets?limit=1000&offset=0';
const notebookUrl = '/api/notebooks?limit=1000&offset=0';
const smartphonesUrl = '/api/smartphones?limit=1000&offset=0';

Promise.all([fetch(tabletUrl), fetch(notebookUrl), fetch(smartphonesUrl)]).then(res => Promise.all(res.map(r => r.json()))).then(data => {
    const dataModel = new JSONModel();
    dataModel.setData({
        items: data.flat()
    });
    this.getView().setModel(dataModel, "aribadevices");
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tested it but it didnt worked. I got also the Warning in the Console: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience". But not an Error Code or something. The Data is not consumed.

Comment: @Dopaemin try updated answer, forgot to get the json from the response

Comment: Still the same output like as before...

Comment: is something wrong with my View?
<List items="{aribadevices>/items}">
      <items>
       <CustomListItem class="list">
        <f:Card class="sapUiMediumMargin" width="300px">
         <f:header>
          <card:Header title="{aribadevices>name}"/>
         </f:header>
         <f:content>
          <Text text="{aribadevices>name}"/>
         </f:content>
        </f:Card>
       </CustomListItem>
      </items>
     </List>

Comment: Youre my Hero. My View was wrong I had to display the arrays with it, I forgot about that, so the Answer was  <List items="{aribadevices>/items/0/results}"> <List items="{aribadevices>/items/1/results}"> <List items="{aribadevices>/items/2/results}">

THANKS A LOT!